# My div disappears after first execution

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, dependency-injection

```html
 <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/EIStyling.css" />
        </head>
        <body>
        <form id="BookOperator" runat="server" visible="True">  
    
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfGlobal_UserSelectedStartBookingTime" runat="server" ></asp:HiddenField> 
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfGlobal_UserSelectedEndBookingTime" runat="server" ></asp:HiddenField>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfGlobal_SelectedUserID" runat="server" ></asp:HiddenField>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfSelectedBookingCancelID" Value="0" runat="server" ></asp:HiddenField>
            
            <ul>
                <li class="ul" ><a href="Home.aspx" class="Mnu" >Home</a></li>
                <li class="ul" ><a class="Mnu" style="cursor:pointer" >Bookings</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li class="li" ><a href="BookVehicle.aspx" class="MnuItem" >Book Vehicle</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="ul" ><a class="Mnu" style="cursor:pointer" >Account </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li class="li" ><a href="Change_Password.aspx" class="MnuItem" >Change Password</a></li>
                        <li class="li" ><a id="LogOut" runat="server" href="LogIn.aspx" onclick="fncLogout()" class="MnuItem" >Log Out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div class="divCalPosition">
                <asp:Calendar ID="clndrBookings" runat="server" 
                    BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" Font-Names="Verdana" 
                    Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" Height="180px" 
                    onselectionchanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged" Width="230px" 
                    FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" BorderStyle="Solid" CellSpacing="1" 
                    NextPrevFormat="ShortMonth">
                    <DayHeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Height="8pt" Font-Size="8pt" 
                        ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <DayStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                    <NextPrevStyle Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
                    <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#CC9966" />
                    <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#333399" ForeColor="White" />
                    <TitleStyle BackColor="#333399" 
                        Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="11pt" ForeColor="White" BorderStyle="Solid" 
                        Height="12pt" />
                    <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="White" />
                </asp:Calendar>
            </div>

            <div id="confirmBooking" runat="server" style="display: none" align="center">

                <p class="p" >Please enter a Destination and Project Code, and
                                <br /> click "Accept" to complete booking, or press "Cancel" to return to previous screen.</p>
                  <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="lblDestination" runat="server" CssClass="lblBook" >Destination:</asp:Label></td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtDestination" runat="server" align="center" Width="230px" ></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="lblProjCode" runat="server" CssClass="lblBook" >Project Code:</asp:Label></td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtProjCode" runat="server" align="center" Width="230px" ></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <asp:Button ID="btnCstm" runat="server" align="center" onclick="btnCstm_Click" 
                                Text="Custom Booking" Width="110px" />  &nbsp
                            <asp:Button ID="btnMkeBook" runat="server" align="center" OnClientClick="return invalidInfo(this)" onclick="btnMkeBook_Click" 
                                Text="Accept" Width="80px" />  &nbsp
                            <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" align="center" onclick="btnCancel_Click" 
                                Text="Cancel" Width="80px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
            </div>
                         <!--Invalid Date Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="InvalidDateModal" role="dialog" style="display:none;">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                        <%--<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>--%>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Warning!</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                 <p> End date cannot be less than Start date.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
                        <!--Invalid Custom Info Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="InvalidCusInfoModal" role="dialog" style="display:none;">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-header">
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Warning!</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                 <p> Destination and Project Code fields cannot be left empty! Make sure all information is filled out properly. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
                        <!--Invalid Info Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="InvalidInfoModal" role="dialog" style="display:none;">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-header">
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Warning!</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                 <p> Destination and Project Code fields cannot be left empty! Make sure all information is filled out properly. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
            </div>

            </div>
                        <!--Invalid Missing Date Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="MissingDateModal" role="dialog" style="display:none;">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                        <%--<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>--%>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Warning!</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                 <p> End date cannot be left empty! Make sure all information is filled out properly.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div id="cnclOrEditBooking" runat="server" style="display:none;" align="center" onclick="lblOnClickEvent_Click">
                <p class="p" align="center" >Would you like to Delete or Edit your booking?</p>
                       
                <asp:Button id="btnUpdateBooking" align="center" runat="server" Text="Edit Booking" OnClick="btnUpdateBooking_Click"  Width="100px" />  &nbsp
                <asp:Button id="btnDelBooking" align="center" runat="server" Text="Delete Booking" Width="102px" OnClick="btnDelBooking_Click" />  &nbsp   
                <asp:Button id="btnEditBack" align="center" runat="server" Text="Back" OnClick="btnCancel_Click"  Width="100px" />
                    
            </div>

            <div id="divBookingCnclCnfrm" runat="server" style="display:none;" align="center" >
                <p class="p" align="center" > Are you sure you want to delete your booking?</p>

                <asp:Button id="btnYes" align="center" runat="server" Text="Yes" OnClick="btnYes_Click" Width="50px" /> &nbsp
                <asp:Button ID="btnNo" align="center" runat="server" Text="No" OnClick="btnNo_Click" Width="50px" />
            </div>

            <div id="CustomBooking" runat="server" style="display:block;" align="center" >
             
                     <p class="p" >PLEASE NOTE THAT CUSTOM BOOKING ONLY APPLIES FOR FULL DAY (08:00 - 17:00) BOOKINGS! <br />
                                   <br /> Enter Destination and Project Code, <br /> and then pick the Start date and the End date, and
                                <br /> click "Accept" to complete booking, or click "Cancel" to return to previous screen.</p>

                   <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCustomDestination" runat="server" CssClass="lblBook" >Destination:</asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCustomDestination" runat="server" align="center" Width="230px" ></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCusProjCode" runat="server" CssClass="lblBook" >Project Code:</asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCusProjCode" runat="server" align="center" Width="230px" ></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>    
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblStartDate" runat="server" CssClass="lblBook" >Start Date:</asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" align="center" Width="150px" 
                                ReadOnly="True" ></asp:TextBox>
                         </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblEndDate" runat="server" CssClass="lblBook" >End Date:</asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="calCustomBookEndDate" size="17" runat="server" 
                                readonly="readonly" />
                        </td>  
                       
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <asp:Button ID="btnCustomBook" runat="server" align="center" 
                                OnClientClick="return invalidInfoCustom(this)" onclick="btnCustomBook_Click" 
                                Text="Accept" Width="80px" /> &nbsp
                            <asp:Button ID="btnCustomCancel" runat="server" align="center" onclick="btnCancel_Click" 
                                Text="Cancel" Width="80px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

             <div id="OpsEditBooking" runat="server" style="display:block; height:400px" align="center" >
               <table style="height: 119px"> 
                 <tr>
                     <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblEditDestination" runat="server" CssClass="lblBook" >Destination:</asp:Label>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditDestination" runat="server" align="center" Width="230px" ></asp:TextBox>
                    
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>    
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblEditProjCode" runat="server" CssClass="lblBook" >Project Code:</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditProjCode" runat="server" align="center" Width="230px" ></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>  
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblEditStartTime" runat="server" CssClass="lblBook" >Start Time:</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStartTimes" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                            onselectedindexchanged="ddlStartTimes_SelectedIndexChanged" >
                                <asp:ListItem>08:00</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>08:30</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>09:00</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>09:30</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>10:00</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>10:30</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>11:00</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>11:30</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>12:00</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>12:30</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>13:00</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>13:30</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>14:00</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>14:30</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>15:00</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>15:30</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>16:00</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>16:30</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblEditEndTime" runat="server" CssClass="lblBook" >End Time:</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEndTimes" runat="server" >
                            <asp:ListItem>08:30</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>09:00</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>09:30</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>10:00</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>10:30</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>11:00</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>11:30</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>12:00</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>12:30</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>13:00</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>13:30</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>14:00</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>14:30</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>15:00</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>15:30</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>16:00</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>16:30</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>17:00</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"> 
                        <asp:Button ID="btnAcceptEdit" runat="server" align="center" 
                        OnClientClick="return invalidInfoEditBooking(this)" onclick="btnAcceptEdit_Click" 
                        Text="Accept" Width="80px" /> &nbsp
                        <asp:Button ID="btnEditCancel" runat="server" align="center" onclick="btnCancel_Click" 
                        Text="Cancel" Width="80px" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
             </table>
            </div>

            <asp:Panel ID="pnlEmpDisp" runat="server" BackColor="Transparent" ScrollBars="Auto" >   
                <div id="dvInfo" runat="server" style="display:block" >                      
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Button id="btnLogOut" runat="server" onclick="btnLogOut_Click" style="display:none;" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have a booking system that allows you to book, delete or edit your booking.When clicking the delete button,
 a `<div>` with the delete confirmation pops up with the two buttons, Yes and No. If you click Yes,
 the booking gets deleted and the user is redirected back to the Home page, where you can view and make other bookings as well.
 This works well during first execution, but if you make another booking and try to delete it, the confirmation `<div>`,
 the one with Yes and No doesn't appear at all until you click the Home button and begin the delete process,
 then it will show. This is my .aspx and .cs code

```html
</div>

 <div id="divBookingCnclCnfrm" runat="server" style="display:none;" align="center" >
 <p class="p" align="center" > Are you sure you want to deleted your booking?</p>

 <asp:Button ID="btnYes" align="center" runat="server" Text="Yes" OnClick="btnYes_Click" Width="50px" /> &nbsp
 <asp:Button ID="btnNo" align="center" runat="server" Text="No" OnClick="btnNo_Click" Width="50px" />
            
 </div>

 protected void btnDelBooking_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            divBookingCnclCnfrm.Style["display"] = "block";
            dvInfo.Visible = false;
            VehEditBooking.Visible = false;
            BuildVechGrid();
        }
```

Comment: Why didn't you use divBookingCnclCnfrm.Visible = false; ?

Comment: Where is the code to hide `divBookingCnclCnfrm` with your buttons? In `BuildVechGrid`? If yes, can you post the code?

Comment: @Bayeni mistake on my question. I meant doesn't appear! See my edit. Apologies. As you can see I set it to "block" but still it breaks, when I change to .Visible = true; it doesn't appear even on first execution

Comment: @krlzlx see my edit and above comment. Apologies

Comment: Can you post the code required to solve your problem? The portions you show are not enough to find where is your problem. For example, where is your `btnDelBooking` button ?

Comment: Share the entire html code

Comment: @krlzlx Please check the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using server side controls, lets just keep it simple and use properties that are available for the control.

Change this line:

```
<div id="divBookingCnclCnfrm" runat="server" style="display:none;" align="center" >
```

to

```
<div id="divBookingCnclCnfrm" runat="server" visible="false" align="center" >
```

Then in the delete button event write:

```
    protected void btnDelBooking_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        divBookingCnclCnfrm.Visible = true;
        dvInfo.Visible = false;
        VehEditBooking.Visible = false;
        BuildVechGrid();
    }
```

Please test and see if it helps.

Comment: Works on some of the forms. Thanks, I will alter the others